# Is there a way to find a member by id in Discord JDA?

Tags: discord, discord-jda

I need my bot to see if a user has a certain id to ban him if him is in the global blacklist, something like:

```
if(member id == 4950385304) {
ban him
}
```

Sorry if i wasn't clear and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the member instance, you can simply check the id:

```java
if (member.getIdLong() == 1234567891234567L) {
    member.ban(0).queue();
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply ban members by id:

```java
guild.ban(1234567891234567L, 0).queue();
```